# SharePoint 2010 update every Socond list item using Powershell SP.Client

Tags: powershell

What I need is to update every **Second** item by using Powershell SharePoint.Client.
I used some code from here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/15/using-powershell-to-get-data-from-a-sharepoint-2010-list.aspx
and added required functionality. Im very new in Powershell so I may have made some silly mistake. Would you kindly check my code and pointed what is that mistake.

```
Add-Type -path C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Add-Type -path C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Function Get-SPClientList { 



$cSharp = @" 

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; 

namespace SPClient 
{ 
    public class SharePointList 
    { 
        public static ListItemCollection GetList() 
        { 
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp10sl1:55555/mychuldesite"); 
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList"); 
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery(); 
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>"; 
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery); 
            clientContext.Load(list);  
            clientContext.Load(listItems); 
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            return listItems; 
        } 
    } 
} 
"@ 
$assemblies = @( 
    "$PSSCriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll", 
    "$PSSCriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
    "System.Core" 
    ) 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies 

$items = [SPClient.SharepointList]::GetList() 

$out = @() 
$i=0
foreach ($item in $items)
{
  if($i % 2 -eq 0)
  {
    $item["Title"] = "ClientTitle";
    $item["UserData"] = "ClientData";
    $item.Update();
  }
  $i += 1
}
$out
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve it.
We can simply add Update logic inside of C# block and then just call this function.

It should looks something like this

```
Add-Type -path C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Add-Type -path C:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll



$cSharp = @"


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
namespace SPClient
{
public class SharePointList
{
public static ListItemCollection GetList()
{
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext ("http://*****:****/*****");
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);


clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
int i=0;
foreach ( ListItem item in listItems)
{
 if(i % 2 == 0)
  {
item["Title"] = "This is client Powershell";
item["UserData"] = "Yeap it is";
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
i++;
}

return listItems;
}
}
}
"@

$assemblies = @( 
    "$PSSCriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll", 
    "$PSSCriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
    "System.Core" 
    ) 

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies 

$its = [SPClient.SharepointList]::GetList()
```

Unfortunatly it takes alot of time for me to fully understand this kind of code without any tutorials, so if you know such, please inform me.